# Django - django-reversion - not working in inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-reversion

I have created a common class with it's admin class which should be inherited by all of my models. My common admin class inherited the VersionAdmin

```
from reversion.admin import VersionAdmin

class CommonAdmin(VersionAdmin):   
    pass
```

The problem is that, the model admins which inherited  CommonAdmin is not showing the deleted model entries in "Recover Items". But If I didn't use inheritance, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following didn't run properly. It works fine now.

```
manage.py createinitialrevisions
```